# SQL Bulk Copy, but rebuilding index takes too long

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, sqlbulkcopy

My sql bulk copy has gotten a lot slower due to bigger database and indexes I think.

So I have a database and an app on VS where I read text file etc and transfer and "sqlbulkcopy" to my database. This was working perfect and at a fast pace but now I have over 50 million records and it has become VERY slow.

I think this is due to the fact I have indexes on my 2 tables but if I was to disable and then rebuild when done it takes way to long, e.g if just uploading 1 file it take few seconds but now takes minutes and even longer if I was to disable and rebuild index, any other suggestions? For people wondering one table takes 15 mins to rebuild all indexes while the other only takes 3.

```
  Dim sqlBulk As New SqlBulkCopy(con)
            'sql bulkcopy table with ticket and file path etc.
            Using sqlBulk
                'tested bulk sizes. no major effect in sizes
                sqlBulk.BatchSize = 10000
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = ("Test_Table")
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt)
            End Using


            Using sqlBulk
                sqlBulk.BatchSize = 10000
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = ("Lnk_Ttks")
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(db)
            End Using
```

This works but like I said it has gotten very slow now seeing as the database is huge.

Comment: The reason the bulk inserts become slower as the table size grows is likely because the index keys are not incremental and you don't have enough RAM or fast enough storage.

Comment: @DanGuzman So is there a way around this? Also when its running according to VS its only using 98 mb of memory

Comment: You may want to start looking into partitioning. 50M rows actually isn't even that big by most DB standards, so you shouldn't really need it (as opposed to beefing up the server or reducing your table/index size) but it's nevertheless a possible solution. On a partitioned table, each partition in effect behaves as if it was its own table with respect to index operations (assuming partitioned indexes as well, of course) so the slowdown is "capped" to the partition size. Partitioning does have a considerable learning curve, though.

Comment: @K.Madden around what? This isn't a VB.NET problem, it has to do you the database, the tables, indexes, hardware. The code you posted doesn't say anything about your data, what indexes are there or where the data is stored

Comment: @K.Madden what is the table's primary key? What is its clustered index? If you try to insert data all over the table you'll get bad performance as the database tries to move data around to keep records in order. If the key is a *GUID*, writes will happen all over the place. Instead of allocating a few data pages as needed, the server may have to move everything around

Comment: @K.Madden if that's the case, partitioning will actually make things slower, not faster. Partitioning is a data management feature, not a performance feature.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `TableLock` options if it's possible in your scenario will increase performance.

It always depends on multiple factors but I often get 30% performance gains and more.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2
- https://sqlbulkcopy-tutorial.net/sqlbulkcopyoptions